# sort div's through sort();

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have list and this list must be sort to a => b throught like btn (example click SORT and we have list to a -> b)

```
<div class = "list">
<div id = "products"> Sugar </div>
<div id = "products"> Banana </div>
<div id = "products"> Apple </div>
</div>
```

sorted to for button =>

```
<div class = "list">
<div id = "products"> Apple </div>
<div id = "products"> Banana </div>
<div id = "products"> Sugar </div>
</div>
```

Idk how did that with like btn :(

I tried something like that =>

```
// For the HTML //

<button class = 'sortBtn' onclick = 'sort()'>Sort</button>

<script>

const sort  = document.quertSelector('.sortBtn');

sort.addEventListenet('click', function sort(a, b){
$parent.sort();
})

</script>
```

I would be grateful for help :) <3

Comment: [Validate your HTML](//validator.nu): duplicate IDs are invalid. `addEventListenet` doesn’t exist, and even if you meant [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), there is no callback function that would accept _two_ arguments; the first one is always going to be an [`Event`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event); it will never be an Element. What does “a => b” or “a -> b” mean? If you want to sort lexicographically in an ascending order, then see [Sorting a list by data-attribute](/a/32199776/4642212) for a related example.

Comment: You misspelled `addEventListener`.

Comment: What is `$parent`? If it's a DOM element, they don't have a built-in `sort()` method. You need to write a function that sorts the divs.

Comment: Why does your `sort()` function take parameters `a` and `b` but not use them? You seem to be confusing the click event listener with the comparison function used with `Array.prototype.sort()`.

Comment: You misspelled querySelector too.

Comment: You can convert the children of a DIV to an array with `[...element.childElements]`. Then you can sort this. Finally, replace the contents of the parent with those elements.

Comment: Closing questions after x minutes is REALLY annoying! I cannot post my answer... But here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/e321u9rj/.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues in your code.

- Typo: `quertSelector` -> `querySelector`
- Typo: `addEventListenet` -> `addEventListener`
- The repeated `id` in your HTML are invalid, convert them to `class` instead.
- The function you provide to `addEventListener` should be anonymous in this case. Giving it a name here serves no purpose other than to waste bytes.
- Avoid using inline event handlers, such as `onclick`, in your HTML code. It's outdated and no longer good practice. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead, such as `addEventListener()`, which you already use elsewhere in your code.
- [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should compare the `a` and `b` arguments and return an integer depending on which way to sort them. In this case, as you're comparing strings you can use `localeCompare()` on the `textContent` property of the elements.
- After the `sort()` has completed you need to update the DOM to respect the new order of the elements. To do this you can call `append()` on the parent element, supplying the children as the argument.

Here's a working example with these issues addressed:

```js
const sortButton = document.querySelector('.sortBtn');
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const products = list.querySelectorAll('.products');

sortButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const sortedElements = Array.from(products).sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent));
  list.append(...sortedElements);
})
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="products">Sugar</div>
  <div class="products">Banana</div>
  <div class="products">Apple</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="sortBtn">Sort</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the children of the parent element to an array. Then you can use the array `sort()` method to sort it, then append the children back to the parent in that order.

```js
document.querySelector(".sortBtn").addEventListener("click", () => sortDiv(document.querySelector(".list")));

function sortDiv(parent) {
  let children = [...parent.children];
  children.sort((a, b) => a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText));
  parent.innerHTML = '';
  children.forEach(child => parent.appendChild(child));
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="products"> Sugar </div>
  <div class="products"> Banana </div>
  <div class="products"> Apple </div>
</div>

<button class='sortBtn'>Sort</button>
```